# 3d triangle in one equation without min or max

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, graphing-functions

How can I graph a **triangle in 3d** with a **single equation** that does not use min, max, floor, ceil, or absolute value?

If you believe not possible, then the closest approximation (equation that roughly appears to be a 3d triangle) will do.

Comment: Do you consider piecewise functions to be a single equation? And how about the use of $\sqrt{x^2}$ in place of $|x|$?

Comment: I do not. However if you believe not possible without it, I am still interested in what you may come up with. Although, to be honest, I am interested most in an equation that is differentiable, so I guess the absolute value function may be ok (not differentiable at zero, but its derivative may be expressed as $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$).

Answer (score 2):

(*Too long for a comment*.) In 2D the segment between $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ can be represented as $\,\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} + \sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2} = \sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}\,$.

Then the equation of a triangle with vertices $\,(x_k,y_k) \;\mid\; k=1,2,3\,$ could be written as:

$$
\prod_{1\le i \lt j \le 3} \left(\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2} + \sqrt{(x-x_j)^2+(y-y_j)^2} - \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2}\right) = 0
$$

The above can easily be extended to 3D, though I don't see any practical use for either.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example of triangle with vertices $(0,0,0)$,$(3,3,0)$ and $(-3,3,0)$

$$((x+y) (x-y)(y-3)(\sqrt{9-x^2- (y-3)^2}+1))^2+z^2=0$$
$a^2+b^2=0$ ensures that $a=0$ and $b=0$. Here $z=0$ denotes equation of plane of triangle. $x+y=0$,$x-y=0$ and $y=3$ are 3 planes that contain 3 lines of triangle. The square root is included to exclude points on the line not a part of triangle.

Comment: The number in the square root must be positive

Comment: How do the vertices (0,0,0) (3,3,0) and (-3,-3,0) form a triangle? Isn't that a line? They all lie on the same line.

Comment: My bad. Corrected